# How to implement Filter2d Opencv in C++ without the builtin function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I did implement the builtin function of Filter2d in opencv c++ and I want to implement it without the builtin function, but I can't. This is what I have tried so far.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    /// Declare variables
    Mat src, dst, dsty;
    Mat kernelx, kernely;
    Point anchor;
    double delta;
    int ddepth;
    int kernel_size;

namedWindow("filter2D", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    src = imread("C:/Users/cvi/Desktop/2.jpg");

    /// Initialize arguments for the filter
    anchor = Point(-1, -1);
    delta = 0;
    ddepth = -1;

    kernel_size = 2;

    kernelx = Mat::ones(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F) /
        (float)(kernel_size*kernel_size);
    kernely = Mat::ones(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F) /
        (float)(kernel_size*kernel_size);

    kernelx.at<float>(0, 0) = -1;
    kernely.at<float>(0, 0) = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j) {
            int tmp, sum;
            for (int m = 0; m < kernelx.rows; ++m) {
                for (int n = 0; n < kernely.cols; ++n) {
                    tmp = src[i + m - (kernel_size - 1) / 2][j + n - (kernel_size - 1) / 2];
                    float kernel_index = kernelx[m][n];
                    float index_mult = (float)index_mult * kernel_index;
                    sum = sum + index_mult;
                }
            }
            imshow("filter2D Change in X", dst);
            imshow("filter2D Change in Y", dsty);
        }
    }
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having with your code? Does it not compile? Does it not read the image? Does it not give an output? Does it not give the correct output? What input are you using and what is the expected output?

Comment: It should read the image ,apply the kernal and filter the image as output

Comment: this is the error i am facing

Comment: no operator "[]" matches these operand

Comment: @beaker if i ask you to help me by giving an example of Filter2d in opencv C++ own implementation without builtin function

Comment: If you're asking for someone to give you code, that's off-topic. Please read the [help/on-topic]. If you're asking for help fixing your code, your question should include specific questions about your code and any error you get (including which line the error occurred on). Please read [ask]. In this case, the error seems pretty clear: there is no `[]` operator for `Mat` objects.

Comment: The answer shows how to apply the sobel kernel. Just change the kernel as needed